# MYSQL Count As, Group By, JSON equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json

Is there any equivalant of

```
mysql_query("SELECT subcategory, COUNT(*) AS subcate FROM database GROUP BY subcategory");
```

in Js-Json that i can count how many unique subcategories are there and print them in a JSON array without filtering them in `mysql_query`?

Suppose that I get full table from database with

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database");
```

And I put it into an `json_encode($array);` then can i count unique subcategories and print them from that JSON array?

JSON DATA

```
[{"category":"fish","subcategory":"angel","name":"angelfish juvenille"},{"category":"fish","subcategory":"angel","name":"angelfish adult"},{"category":"fish","subcategory":"clownfish","name":"clownfish juvenille"},{"category":"fish","subcategory":"clownfish","name":"clownfish adult"]
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. JSON is a technique of encoding a string. It has nothing to do with databases or the queries executed on them

Comment: can u please post your ajax code from where you are getting that data.

Comment: You didnt understand me i belive. Suppose i get full database into an JSON array and using it with JS. What is the JS method to print unique usernames? There is nothing with ajax mate, I dont even use any ajax for this. At top of the page i write php code and echo the json_encoded array into JS.@PrateikDarji @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I think you want the using like SQL Query's method on "JSON DATA" with using JavaScript right?. If you want this, can you share your json? At least a part for example. @GüneySaramalı

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL Aynen kardeşim. Alright im editing question with adding the JSON DATA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a simple reduce on the list of data. You keep an object with a key for every subcategory, the value is the amount of elements with that specific subcategory:

```js
 var data = [{"category":"fish","subcategory":"angel","name":"angelfish juvenille"},{"category":"fish","subcategory":"angel","name":"angelfish adult"},{"category":"fish","subcategory":"clownfish","name":"clownfish juvenille"},{"category":"fish","subcategory":"clownfish","name":"clownfish adult"}]

var result=  data.reduce((all, element) => { 
   all[element.subcategory] = (all[element.subcategory] || 0) +1;
   return all
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That was what i asked for. Thank You very much. Now i dont need to create mysql_query for everytime i need to filter data but i will get whole data and filter it with js.